# How to filter out only digits in a given string using Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm given an assignment in which I have an array of strings. And my task is to filter out the digits only and save them in an array of Integer using the Stream API. So far I have done this:

```java
String [] data={"Mehrose-150891","Rachel-150892","Roni-148269"}


 Integer[] digitsOnly= Arrays.stream(data)
                       .map(x->new Character((char)x))
                       .filter(Character::isDigit)
```

I am given an error on a call of map **Can not cast from String to char**, if I can get an explanation on this that would be helpful. Moreover, I don't have any idea how do I directly get an array of Integer rather than to get a list of Character.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: Is it only in this format NUMBER1-NUMBER2?

Comment: @NotaJD bro don’t have the code now but what I done was , i converted the string to char array then i made an int array of string’s length then by for loop i copied the chararray to intarray using character.getdecimalvalue

Comment: @MS90 N0, there can be many numbers in a string depend on user. For example “53736372” or “63738” but the string will only contains numbers

Comment: So, what does it mean? If you have 0-9, does it mean store all numbers from 0 to 9( like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9) or just 0 and 9 in an array? @Mehrose

Comment: @MS90 yes it has to store from 0,1.......,9

Comment: Take a look at my answer then. @Mehrose

Comment: @MS90 that's work fine for me but if i had to convert this string"5345869" as an int array{5,3,4,5,8,6,9}, How would I be do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at following code using Java8 and streams feature:

**For situtations like X-X, where X denotes number smaller than 10**

```
String number = "0-9";
int[] stream = IntStream.range(Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(0)),Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(2))+1).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stream));
```

**For situtations like nX-nX, where nX denotes any number**

```
 String number2 = "36335-36363";
 int[] stream2 = IntStream.range( // stream range
 Integer.parseInt(number2.substring(0, number2.indexOf("-"))), 
 Integer.parseInt(number2.substring(number2.indexOf("-")+1))+1 
).toArray();
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stream2));
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in one line, breaks inserted for readability.

```
IntStream.range( // stream range
    Integer.parseInt(string.substring(0, string.indexOf("-"))), // get first number
    Integer.parseInt(string.substring(string.indexOf("-")+1))+1 // get second number
).toArray(int[]::new); // collect to an array
```